# How can we find out battery level info of Beacons

Tags: node.js, ibeacon, beacon

I am detecting beacons and getting JSON data from which I can get Mac Address of Beacon but I need information about battery level.
Currently I am using node js and using Noble module for searching beacons.

```
var https = require('https'),
myip = require('quick-local-ip'),
noble = require('noble'),
os = require('os'),
amqp = require('amqp');

noble.on('stateChange', function (state) {
if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    console.log("start scanning");
    noble.startScanning([], true);
} else {
    noble.removeAllListener();
    noble.stopScanning();
    console.log("stop scanning, is Bluetooth on?");
}



noble.on('discover', function (peripheral) {console.log("peripheral - "+peripheral);}
```

Output -

```
{
"id": "ac233f244b34",
"address": "ac:23:3f:24:4b:34",
"addressType": "public",
"connectable": true,
"advertisement": {
    "manufacturerData": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [76, 0, 2, 21, 226, 197, 109, 181, 223, 251, 72, 210, 176, 96, 208, 245, 167, 16, 150, 224, 0, 1, 0, 1, 129]
    },
    "serviceData": [{
        "uuid": "feaa",
        "data": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [32, 0, 12, 120, 24, 0, 0, 0, 251, 140, 1, 223, 146, 120]
        }
    }],
    "serviceUuids": ["feaa"],
    "solicitationServiceUuids": [],
    "serviceSolicitationUuids": []
},
"rssi": -48,
"state": "disconnected"
```

}

How can I Get to know about Battery level from this data.

Comment: https://github.com/noble/noble/issues/683 You can use this.

Comment: I am getting Data in peripheral.Do I need to implement other methods ?